# Script error while using python 3.8 but error shows python should be greater than python 2.7

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

I am using python 3.8 but an error showing python should be greater than 2.7. Adding a pic to give you an overview of the [image]question.

Comment: Check what is in the script you are running. It could literally use os.system to run python 2.7, for example

Comment: this get-pip.py is using "import sys"..So how can I solve this ?

Comment: Try `python3` instead of `python`

Comment: how i can do it? HELP